# Using Wild Card on Airflow GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator

Tags: python, airflow

Is it possible to use a wildcard on GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator?

So I have a collection of files inside a certain folder in GCS

```
file_sample_1.json
file_sample_2.json
file_sample_3.json
...
file_sample_n.json
```

I want to ingest these files using airflow with GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator.

below is my code:

```
    def create_operator_write_init():
        return GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id = 'test_ingest_to_bq',
            bucket = 'sample-bucket-dev-202211',
            source_objects = 'file_sample_1.json',
            destination_project_dataset_table = 'sample_destination_table',
            create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            source_format = "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
            schema_fields = [
                {"name": "id", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
                {"name": "created_at", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
                {"name": "updated_at", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
            ]
        )
```

It can ingest 1 file just fine, but I need the source_object to have wild card, can I do something like 'file_sample_*.json' so that the * will act as a wild card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you should include the string in a list. So if you use

```
source_objects = ['file_sample_*.json'],
```

it will ingest all files starting with 'file_sample_' and ending with '.json'.

Comment: thanks! why didn't I think to state them as a list in the first place? :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating apache-airflow-providers-google to version 8.5.0. where wildcard stoped to work.
You can dowmgrade to version 8.4.0. or if you are using airflow and google operators also to load data to bigquery, filenames are pushed to XCOM from that operators.

So as the workaround, I read that values from XCOM and use them as an argument for GCSToBigQueryOperator